# Javascript image won't show up

Tags: javascript

I know next to nothing about javascript but the I am able to read the code and understand what's going on (I think).  I just need to insert a game into a project for school and manipulate the formats etc to match my project.  This isn't going public or anything.  So I inserted this free game, but it won't let me change the picture.  I don't understand why.  I tried making the var x on line 2 of the javascript equal to var x= new image (..), and tried putting the image directly in the code on line 199.  The first try broke the code and the second try didn't do anything.  What am I missing here?? I appreciate your wisdom.

tictac.js

```
<!-- Begin
var x = "../images/americanPeregrineFalconsm.jpg";  //**Line 2**
// Location of where you uploaded your site's x.jpg image

var o = "../images/carolinaWrensm.jpg";
// Location of where you uploaded your site's o.jpg image

var blank = "../images/highlight-bg.png";
// Location of where you uploaded your site's blank.jpg image
.
.
.
.

function yourChoice(chName) 
    {
        pause = 0;
        if (all!=0) ended();
        if (all==0) 
        {
            cf = 0;
            ok = 0;
            temp=chName;
            checkSpace();
            if (ok==1) 
            {
                document.images[chName].src = x;  //***LINE 199****
            }

            if (ok==0)taken();
            process();
            if ((all==0)&&(pause==0)) myChoice();
         }
    }

function taken() {
alert("That square is already occupied.  Please select another square.")
pause=1;
}
function myChoice() {
temp="";
ok = 0;
cf=1;
logicTwo();
logicThree();
checkSpace();
while(ok==0) {
aRandomNumber=Math.random()
comp=Math.round((choice-1)*aRandomNumber)+1;
if (comp==1) temp="A";
if (comp==2) temp="B";
if (comp==3) temp="C";
if (comp==4) temp="D";
if (comp==5) temp="E";
if (comp==6) temp="F";
if (comp==7) temp="G";
if (comp==8) temp="H";
if (comp==9) temp="I";
checkSpace();
}
document.images[temp].src= "../images/carolinaWrensm.jpg";
process();
}
function ended() {
alert("The game has already ended. To play a new game click the Play Again button.")
}
function process() {
logicOne();
if (all==1){ alert("You won, congratulations!"); wn++; }
if (all==2){ alert("Gotcha!  I win!"); ls++; }
if (all==3){ alert("We tied."); ts++; }
if (all!=0) {
document.game.you.value = wn;
document.game.computer.value = ls;
document.game.ties.value = ts;
   }
}
function playAgain() {
if (all==0) {
if(confirm("This will restart the game and clear all the current scores. OK?")) reset();
}
if (all>0) reset();
}
function reset() {
all = 0;
a = 0;
b = 0;
c = 0;
d = 0;
e = 0;
f = 0;
g = 0;
h = 0;
i = 0;
temp="";
ok = 0;
cf = 0;
choice=9;
aRandomNumber = 0;
comp = 0;
document.images.A.src= blank;
document.images.B.src= blank;
document.images.C.src= blank;
document.images.D.src= blank;
document.images.E.src= blank;
document.images.F.src= blank;
document.images.G.src= blank;
document.images.H.src= blank;
document.images.I.src= blank;
if (t==0) { t=2; myChoice(); }
t--;
}
```

---

Here's the html that goes with it in case you need to see it. 
tictac.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Freebird Game: Carolina Avian Society</title>
        <meta charset=utf-8">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tictac.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
            .
            .
            .
            .

            <section>
                <center>
                  <form name=game>
                      <table border=0>
                      <td>
                      <table border=1>
                      <tr>
                      <td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('A')"><img src="images/highlight-bg.png" border=0 height=100 width=100 name=A alt="Top-Left"></a></td>
                      <td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('B')"><img src="images/highlight-bg.png" border=0 height=100 width=100 name=B alt="Top-Center"></a></td>
                      <td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('C')"><img src="images/highlight-bg.png" border=0 height=100 width=100 name=C alt="Top-Right"></a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('D')"><img src="images/highlight-bg.png" border=0 height=100 width=100 name=D alt="Middle-Left"></a></td>
                      <td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('E')"><img src="images/highlight-bg.png" border=0 height=100 width=100 name=E alt="Middle-Center"></a></td>
                      <td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('F')"><img src="images/highlight-bg.png" border=0 height=100 width=100 name=F alt="Middle-Right"></a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('G')"><img src="images/highlight-bg.png" border=0 height=100 width=100 name=G alt="Bottom-Left"></a></td>
                      <td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('H')"><img src="images/highlight-bg.png" border=0 height=100 width=100 name=H alt="Bottom-Center"></a></td>
                      <td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('I')"><img src="images/highlight-bg.png" border=0 height=100 width=100  name=I alt="Bottom-Right"></a></td>
                      </tr>
                      </table>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                      <table>
                      <tr><td><input type=text size=5 name=you></td><td>You</td></tr>
                      <tr><td><input type=text size=5 name=computer></td><td>Computer</td></tr>
                      <tr><td><input type=text size=5 name=ties></td><td>Ties</td></tr>
                      </table>
                      </td>
                      </table>
                      <input type=button value="Play Again" onClick="playAgain();">
                      &nbsp;&nbsp;
                      <input type=button value="Game Help" onClick="help();">
                      &nbsp;&nbsp;
                      <input type=button value="Quit Game" onClick="quitGame();">
                  </form>
              </center>
            </section>
      .
      .
      .   
      . 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tictac.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code overkill. Please try to narrow your code down to what your question is actually about :)

Comment: ok, thanks...I eliminated a lot of the code that shouldn't have anything to do with the issue...the lines in question are also commented in the code

Comment: is the image definitely in the `images` folder, as the same level as your `js` folder, and named the same?

Comment: Yes, the image is in a folder called images which is in the same directory as the js folder

Comment: I've quadruple checked the image.  This just doesn't make sense to me.  I can't image why it won't show up.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there was some sort of issue wit the file name itself.  That leads me to believe the file name must be referenced in more places than the ones I found (although I can't find them for the life of me).  So I started with the original code all over again, but kept the authors original file names for the images.

I simple saved over them with something else.  I guess it is true that the best thing to do is start over from the beginning sometimes and go one step at a time.  Thank you again to everyone for the suggestions.